# Why is def function(str(n)) an invalid syntax? - python

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

The task is to define a function which adds all the digits of a number. First I have to convert the input (int) into a string. Then I put each string into a list then add them all together. But I can't get past this:

```
def digit(str(n)):
     # the rest of the code
```

without seeing this:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You can't modify n, in the parameters. You would have to do it in the rest of the code area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in python you can't write `def digit(str(n)):`

You need to take the `str(n)` out of the definition and put it into the main code. This should hopefully do the trick:

```
def digit(n):
    n = str(n)
    # the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a function directly on an argument like that. If you wish to do so, you should do it in the function's body:

```
def digit(n):
    n = str(n)
    # the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid syntax because you are expected to define a prototype there, not code.

A prototype is the signature of a function  composed of :
- keyword def
- function name
- list of parameters (python does not require their explicit types to be mentioned)

Ex : def digit( n )